# Сделать точку доступа wi-fi из Win 10

Tags: windows, сеть, администрирование, vpn

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите как стандартными средствами Win10 расшарить VPN соединение для wifi?

Поясняю: Есть Машина с win10 и двумя сетевыми картами. Одна (LAN ethernet) смотрит в сеть провайдера, получает серый dhcp (без доступа в инет) и далее через эту же сеть поднимается VPN который имеет доступ в интернет. Вторая сетевая карта (WLAN) с помощью стандартной утилиты "Мобильный хот-спот" настроена в режим AP и раздаёт лок. сеть 192.168.x.x к которой я успешно коннекчусь по wi-fi с гаджета. Так вот как мне попасть теперь в интернет через VPN поднятый на машине (НЕ на гаджете)? Схему прилагаю: http://uploads.ru/S5MsT.png

P.S. [1] Расшарить общий доступ к VPN через свойства - не вкатывает. Он расшаривается, но инет всё так же недоступен. Если есть соображения как это дебажить без банального traceroute на гаджете - готов выслушать.

P.S. [2] Если есть бесплатные opensource утилиты вроде dragonfly под win10 облегчающие этот процесс - велкам.

Comment: Пользовался утилитой [MyPublicWiFi](http://www.mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html) правда, интернет был не по VPN, а по Ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет!
Тут такое дело что твой телефон получает ip адрес вида 192.168.x.x от утилиты "Мобильный хот-спот", а так как в Windows 10 по умолчанию включен брандмауэр и выключена маршрутизация понять в чем причина того что он не шарит VPN сложно. Как вариант подключится к wifi с ноута и посмотреть таблицу маршрутизации, а там уже tracert'ом разбиратся куда уходят пакеты.

P.S. Есть утилита MyPublicWiFi вроде она может то, что нужно (не знаю платная она или нет)

Comment: Вы гений. Действительно, дело было просто в выключенной службе "маршрутизация". Далее после включения, я разрулил трафик банально системными маршрутами. Большое спасибо за наводку, просто я не очень большой специалист windows-сетей!